# remove rows and ValueError Arrays were different lengths

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, valueerror

My dataframe has subcategory, under each category (`cat`, `dog`, `bird`), stats information is presented. I need to remove the rows if they contain info in `count` and `freq`, and only keep rows with `sd` and `mean` values. Some values are  `NaN`.

`ValueError` occurs in my codes.

df:

```
 var    stats    A     B     C
 cat     mean    2     3     4
 NaN     sd      2     1     3
 NaN     count   5     2     6
 NaN     freq    3     1     19
 dog     mean    8     1     2
 NaN     sd      2     1     3
 NaN     count   4     6     1
 NaN     freq    3     1     19   
 bird    mean    2     3     4
 NaN     sd      2     1     3
 NaN     count   5     2     6
 NaN     freq    NaN   NaN   NaN
```

My codes:

```
rows = ['count', 'freq']
df = [df.stats != rows]
```

Expected outcome

```
 var    stats    A     B     C
 cat     mean    2     3     4
 NaN     sd      2     1     3
 dog     mean    8     1     2
 NaN     sd      2     1     3   
 bird    mean    2     3     4
 NaN     sd      2     1     3
```

error:

```
File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 805, in pandas._libs.lib.vec_compare 
(pandas/_libs/lib.c:14288)
ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 819 vs 9
```

I am not sure how to check the array length, but in my excel spreadsheet, all columns and rows have the same length. Is this error caused by NaN/empty cell in my data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`!=` will not work here. Use `pd.Series.isin` to obtain a mask you'll then use to filter your dataframe.

```
m = ~df.stats.isin(['count', 'freq'])
print(m)
0      True
1      True
2     False
3     False
4      True
5      True
6     False
7     False
8      True
9      True
10    False
11    False
Name: stats, dtype: bool

print(df[m])
    var stats    A    B    C
0   cat  mean  2.0  3.0  4.0
1   NaN    sd  2.0  1.0  3.0
4   dog  mean  8.0  1.0  2.0
5   NaN    sd  2.0  1.0  3.0
8  bird  mean  2.0  3.0  4.0
9   NaN    sd  2.0  1.0  3.0
```

Comment: thanks! Is `~` is similar with `!=`? When should I use `!=`?

Comment: @Kay `!=` is a binary operator, `~` is a unary operator that pandas overloads for negating boolean values.

Answer (score 3):

you can use SQL-like [`query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method:

```
In [163]: df.query("stats not in ['count','freq']")
Out[163]:
    var stats    A    B    C
0   cat  mean  2.0  3.0  4.0
1   NaN    sd  2.0  1.0  3.0
4   dog  mean  8.0  1.0  2.0
5   NaN    sd  2.0  1.0  3.0
8  bird  mean  2.0  3.0  4.0
9   NaN    sd  2.0  1.0  3.0
```

or using your `rows` variable:

```
In [164]: df.query("stats not in @rows")
Out[164]:
    var stats    A    B    C
0   cat  mean  2.0  3.0  4.0
1   NaN    sd  2.0  1.0  3.0
4   dog  mean  8.0  1.0  2.0
5   NaN    sd  2.0  1.0  3.0
8  bird  mean  2.0  3.0  4.0
9   NaN    sd  2.0  1.0  3.0
```

Comment: Nice one. Would you also add an example where the list is declared outside, and the variable referenced with @?

Answer (score 3):

For fun!

```
rows = ['count', 'freq']

df.merge(pd.DataFrame(dict(stats=np.setdiff1d(df.stats, rows))))

    var stats    A    B    C
0   cat  mean  2.0  3.0  4.0
1   dog  mean  8.0  1.0  2.0
2  bird  mean  2.0  3.0  4.0
3   NaN    sd  2.0  1.0  3.0
4   NaN    sd  2.0  1.0  3.0
5   NaN    sd  2.0  1.0  3.0
```

---

Another interesting way with `index` and `drop`

```
df.set_index('stats').drop(rows).reset_index()

  stats   var    A    B    C
0  mean   cat  2.0  3.0  4.0
1    sd   NaN  2.0  1.0  3.0
2  mean   dog  8.0  1.0  2.0
3    sd   NaN  2.0  1.0  3.0
4  mean  bird  2.0  3.0  4.0
5    sd   NaN  2.0  1.0  3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

LOL :)

```
df[[x not in rows for x in df.stats]]
Out[520]: 
    var stats    A    B    C
0   cat  mean  2.0  3.0  4.0
1   NaN    sd  2.0  1.0  3.0
4   dog  mean  8.0  1.0  2.0
5   NaN    sd  2.0  1.0  3.0
8  bird  mean  2.0  3.0  4.0
9   NaN    sd  2.0  1.0  3.0
```