# Filter dataframe by a list of possible prefixes for specific column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

What I'm trying to do is:

```
options = ['abc', 'def']
df[any(df['a'].str.startswith(start) for start in options)]
```

I want to apply a filter so I only have entries that have values in the column 'a' starting with one of the given options.

the next code works, but I need it to work with several options of prefixes...

```
start = 'abc'
df[df['a'].str.startswith(start)]
```

The error message is

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Read [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o) but haven't got understanding of how to do so.

Comment: Show us your data set,please!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a tuple of options to startswith

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['abcd', 'def5', 'xabc', '5abc1', '9def', 'defabcb']})
options = ['abc', 'def']
df[df.a.str.startswith(tuple(options))]
```

You get

```
    a
0   abcd
1   def5
5   defabcb
```

Comment: sorry, something else didn't go well with your solution, so at the end I did it another way - that's why I unmarked it. I'll add my answer as well.

Comment: Found out the reason why I did something else and it's not the limitation of your solution, so I accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
mask = np.array([df['a'].str.startswith(start) for start in options]).any(axis=1)
```

it creates a `Series` for each `start` option and applies `any` along corresponding rows.

You were getting the error because built-in expects a list of `bool`s but as the error message suggests "The truth value of a multiple valued object is ambiguous", so you rather need to use an array-aware `any`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But doesn't Series's any return one of the matching items instead of bool result?

Comment: Do you mean `Series.any()`? It returns `True` if any of Series' elements evaluates to `True` and `False` otherwise.

Comment: yeah, I got confused because functions have the same name and behavior is slightly different... though think of any([...]) as a function that gets any of the True values in the array, it's the same. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, exactly. What you rather needed in turn is applying `any` across multiple `Series` row-wise. Luckily, the simpler and more plausible solution exists with passing a tuple to `startswith` (suggested by Vaishali).

Answer (score 0):

One more solution:

```
# extract all possible values for 'a' column
all_a_values = df['a'].unique()
# filter 'a' column values by my criteria
accepted_a_values = [x for x in all_a_values if any([str(x).startswith(prefix) for prefix in options])]
# apply filter
df = df[df['a'].isin(accepted_a_values))]
```

Took it from here: [remove rows and ValueError Arrays were different lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46655712/remove-rows-and-valueerror-arrays-were-different-lengths)

The solution provided by @Vaishali is the most simple and logical, but I needed the *accepted_a_values* list to iterate trough as well. This was not mentioned in the question, so I mark her answer as correct.